# New page has incorrect URL

Tags: pages, urls

I just installed WordPress on my new dedicated server (running Debian) and each time a create a new page in the WP admin board, it has the URL

```
www.mydomain.com/index.php/mynewpage
```

I would like it to be

```
www.mydomain.com/mynewpage
```

what should I do ? I never had this issue with other installs but I was always on a shared server.

Comment: What is the permalink configuration in WordPress?

Comment: Indeed, it was mydomain.com/index.php/%......, I modified it and it worked thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify the permalink configuration which was set on

```
www.mydomain.com/index.php/%....
```

Just deleted the `index/php` and it worked